# Apache with virtualenv and mod_wsgi : ImportError : No module named 'django'

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, pythonpath

I'm trying to serve a little django project with the following Apache configuration :

**Apache virtualhost configuration :**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName servername

    [...]

    <Directory "/path/to/project/project">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/path/to/project:/path/to/Envs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages                           
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/project/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

I also have the following wsgi.py :

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "example.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have no problem to serve STATIC files and MEDIA files.

I also checked permissions and tried to recursively use 755, then 777 to my virtualenv's site-package directory. It didn't work.

But when trying to reach the root of my site I get the following :

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I guessed that it was a **Python path** related problem since django is installed in my virtualenv. But I added the relevant python paths to the `WSGIDaemonProcess`'s `python-path` attribute so I don't get why it doesn't work.

I also guess I could [add the relevant directory to my Python path in my wsgi.py by using the `site` module](https://serverfault.com/a/421384/342516), but I'd like to understand why the Apache configuration I tried isn't enough. Did I miss something?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088010/wsgi-importerror-no-module-named-hello-module-in-the-same-directory-of-the-ma/59089237#59089237) solve the problem for you too?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are missing a `WSGIProcessGroup` directive or equivalent option on `WSGIScriptAlias`, so your application isn't actually being run in that daemon process group where you have set the virtual environment.

See [Using mod_wsgi daemon mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode)

I would also recommend ensuring application group is set to '%{GLOBAL}' if that is the only application you are running in the daemon process group.

Thus use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/project/wsgi.py \
    process-group=project application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Also better to use `python-home` for the virtual environment.

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/path/to/project \
        python-home=/path/to/Envs/venv
```

See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Answer (score 7):

My rep is not over 50 so I cannot comment, but I'd like to share my discovery.

In WSGIDaemonProcess, if you are using Python 3.5, you need to set exactly as @graham-dumpleton say, with

```
python-home=/path/to/Envs/venv
```

set explicitly.

However, if you are using Python 3.4 (or some older version Python like 2.7 as far as I know), you'll have to configure it as

```
python-path=/path/to/project:/path/to/Envs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

just like what the asker did.

Really weird.

Comment: If using Python 3.4 or 2.7, you should still use ``python-home``. I know of no issues with using the non preferred way of setting ``python-path``, but it simply isn't what you should be doing. The ``python-home`` option has been the best way of setting the location of the virtual environment for a long time. So long that even Linux distros with ancient mod_wsgi versions should still work. This is the case even if the documentation may still not have been updated. :-)

Comment: @graham-dumpleton Thanks for your advice. But in my case, I'm using python 3.4, and the setting was the "python-home" way as you mentioned. However, my site cannot be visited, as Apache keeps sending error "Import Error:No module named 'site'". As long as I configure it to "non preferred way", using ":" like the asker did, this issue was solved. And yes, for Python 3.5, you should use "python-home" way, or [ImportError : No module named 'django'] issue will rise.

Comment: That means your mod_wsgi is not actually compiled for that version of Python. You cannot force mod_wsgi to use a different Python version than it was compiled for. One of the problems with using ``python-path`` is that it doesn't show as well when you are doing the wrong thing and trying to force mod_wsgi to use a virtual environment for a different Python version than mod_wsgi is compiled for. When using ``python-home`` it will instead fail properly thus telling you that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Use the documented check for determining what Python version mod_wsgi is compiled for. If it isn't the Python version you want to use, you must uninstall mod_wsgi and install from a package one for the correct version, or compile from source code to ensure is for correct version. Do not use ``python-path`` to workaround it, as it will fail later in strange ways. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was I had mod wsgi installed for python2. I had to reinstall it for python3:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I was running `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` on python version 3.9. When I rolled back the python version to 3.7, there was no issue.