# Apache virtualenv and mod_wsgi : ImportError : No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm having issues running django and apache2/mod_wsgi. This is my current setup:

```
Ubuntu: 16.0
Apache: 2.4.18
Python: 3.5
Django: 1.10
```

I have installed a virtualenv inside my django project for user 'carma'. Structure is:

```
/home/carma/mycarma
|- manage.py
static
mycarma
    |__init__.py
    |settings.py
    |urls.py
    |wsgi.py
mycarmanev
    bin
    include
    lib
```

This is the content of **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /home/carma/mycarma/static
    <Directory /home/carma/mycarma/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/carma/mycarma/mycarma>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mycarma python-path=/home/carma/mycarma/ python-home=/home/carma/mycarma/mycarmavirtuale$
    WSGIProcessGroup mycarma
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/carma/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py
```

This is the content of **wsgi.py**

```
import os,sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
DJANGO_PATH =  os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..')
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PATH)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mycarma.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And I have already given permissions:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/carma/mycarma/mycarmaenv
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/carma/mycarma
```

The problem comes when I try to access the url of my server, checking the apache log this is the issue:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 25183] mod_wsgi (pid=25183): Target WSGI script '/home/carma/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 25183] mod_wsgi (pid=25183): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/carma/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 25183] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 25183] File "/home/carma/mycarma/mycarma/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 25183] from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 25183] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I have read all the possible discussions here and outside, found also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38756969/apache-with-virtualenv-and-mod-wsgi-importerror-no-module-named-django) which expose exactly the same problem but nothing worked for me.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: did you checked django is correctly installed or not using `pip freeze` command....

Comment: What version of Python is mod_wsgi compiled for. Likely it is not Python 3.5 and so it is ignoring your Python virtual environment. What do you get for ``ldd`` on the ``mod_wsgi.so`` file. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library

Comment: Your env is `mycarmanev` or `mycarmavirtuanev` ?

Comment: Missed that. Yes, the path to ``python-home`` should be what ``sys.prefix`` is for the virtual environment. It doesn't seem to match your layout.

Comment: @itzmeontv: yes the virtualenv is different

Comment: @itzmeontv good catch, thanks for that. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a typo, `mycarmanev` or `mycarmavirtuanev` ?

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mycarma python-path=/home/carma/mycarma/ python-home=/home/carma/mycarma/myprojectenv
```