# WSGI: ImportError: No module named hello (module in the same directory of the main .py file)

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

This is not a duplicate of [Apache with virtualenv and mod_wsgi : ImportError : No module named 'django'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38756969/apache-with-virtualenv-and-mod-wsgi-importerror-no-module-named-django) since here I'm *not* using any virtualenv, and also I'm *not* trying to import another framework's module (such as django), but just a module *in the same directory*.

---

Here is my setup:

`/var/www/test/app.py`:

```
import os, time, sys
from bottle import route, run, template, default_app

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import hello

@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world Python ' + sys.version

application = default_app()
```

`/var/www/test/hello.py`:

```
# just an example module
def test():
    print 'hello'
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  <Directory />
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test/app.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess test user=www-data group=www-data processes=5 threads=5 display-name=test python-path=/var/www/test/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I get:

> ImportError: No module named hello

What is incorrect? Shouldn't `WSGIDaemonProcess  ... python-path=/var/www/test/` help the module `hello` to be loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

- to have a `WSGIDaemonProcess ... python-path=...` indeed,
- **but also a `WSGIScriptAlias ... process-group=...`** (not sure why this `process-group` parameter is linked to allowing or not to load modules from the same directory, but it works!)

Example:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test/app.py process-group=test
WSGIDaemonProcess test user=www-data group=www-data processes=5 threads=5 display-name=test python-path=/var/www/test/
```

See also: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#apache-mod-wsgi

Answer (score 1):

Apache does not change to the current working directory, thus it will not search for hello where you think.

You might change app.py in following way.

```
import os, time, sys
from bottle import route, run, template, default_ap
# add the scripts directory to the python path so that hello can be found
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Advantage you do not have to mess with the apache config files

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I already did this in `app.py`: `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`, why is this not enough?

Comment: changing the directory from within python is  not working. It just changes the working directory, but no more the pythonpath.  You have to change the `pythonpath`  (`sys.path`)

Comment: Oh ok, [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is different, you're right.

Comment: `sys.path` is the variable within python, that combines the contents of the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` and some other autodetermined values

So `sys.path.insert(0, "path_to_add")` shall do the job

Comment: Thanks! But still, look at my initial config in the question, I already have appended this to the WSGI configuration: `python-path=/var/www/test/`, why isn't it working with that? It's stange, don't you think so? The parameter `WSGIDaemonProcess ... python-path=...` should be exactly for this, but here it seems it's not taken in consideration if no `WSGIScriptAlias ... process-group=...` is given...

Comment: I don't use apache, can't help there. but try my code. Perhaps others can explain what's wrong with the apache config